# Language Communication Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

5 professors — A, B, C. D and E — met at a conference and were planning to discuss their Ideas with each other. Each professor speaks exactly two languages among English. French. Russian. Chinese and Hindi. Further. any two professors can discuss their ideas with each other only if they speak at least one language in common.

It is also known that no two professors speak the same set of two languages and each language is spoken by exactly two professors.

Further, it is also known that:

> A can discuss his ideas with C.
>
> B, who speaks English, can discuss his ideas with E.
>
> One of the professors who speaks Russian can discuss his ideas with one of the professors who speaks French.
>
> One of the languages that C speaks is Chinese, and he can discuss his ideas with E.
>
> D speaks Hindi but not English, while E speaks French.

Who speaks with whom?

Source : imsindia.com

Please tell the approach.

Comment: Did you create this, or did you find it somewhere else? If it is the latter, may you provide a source?

Comment: Is this solvable?  I took a quick try at solving and it seems unlikely... unless by `B, who speaks English, can discuss his ideas with E` means that they discuss in English

Comment: @Greg they can share their other language, most likely.

Comment: @Greg from what I understand it will mean either B speaks French as well or E speaks English

Comment: Yeah, that's my understanding as well.  I'm not sure there are enough hints

Comment: sam, you have posted a very large number of aptitude-test-type questions. For a while you indicated that many of them came from imsindia.com but you have stopped doing this (whether because you are no longer copying their questions, or just because you've stopped admitting it, I don't know). **Could you please clarify whether these questions are of your own creation or whether you are taking them from elsewhere?** Thank you.

Comment: I've found [this version](https://parade.com/659476/marilynvossavant/language-logic-puzzle/)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I take the idea of the puzzle from imsindia.com but i dont copy it verbatim. I try to change it as much as possible.

Comment: @sam Maybe you should try to make a question entirely on your own, of this type or other types even. You seem to be struggling with this type of question so maybe have a look at ones with similar tags on this site to see what they do differently and try and make your own question (entirely on your own, without taking any parts from other sources so you don't end up getting closed as you have in the past). Or as I said above maybe now is time to try some different puzzle types. Up to you how you proceed from here but you do have to make some kind of change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found another way that could work:

> A: Chinese, Russian. 
>  B: English, Hindi. 
>  C: Chinese, French. 
>  D: Hindi, Russian. 
>  E: French, English.

Actually I think it's *the* other way it could work since:

> You can substitute Russian for Hindi in A's case because it is the only one without one definite language. Then B can know Russian instead of Hindi. This way both B and A can still communicate with D and their other partners.     
>  
>  Like Excited Raichu I just used trial and error, I started with the certainties and noted down what they all *could* know and worked out what the next guy would *have* to know for the previous guys combination of languages to work. When it didn't work I tried a different combination of languages that the first guy could know etc. 
>  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE, nice answer! +1 from me!

Answer (score 4):

> A: Hindi, Chinese 
>  B: Russian, English
> C: Chinese, French
> D: Hindi, Russian
> E: French, English 
>  
>  Approach: I used trial and error, there are only so many reasonable options to try.